# tsql merge columns into one table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

How to merge columns into one table?

```
declare @map_old table(ID int not null) 
insert into @map_old select 1
insert into @map_old select 2

declare @map_new table(ID int not null) 
insert into @map_new select 11
insert into @map_new select 22

declare @map(ID int not null, ID2 int not null)
```

the result in @map should be:

```
ID   ID2
1    11
2    22
```

Any suggestions? Thx!

Comment: Why `1 11`  and not `1 22`? You need to 'paste' table side by side?

Comment: I need for each row a relation to second table... each tabe has the same row count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use identity in the tables like as follows:

```
declare @map_old table(iden int identity,ID int not null) 
insert into @map_old select 1
insert into @map_old select 2

declare @map_new table(iden int identity,ID int not null) 
insert into @map_new select 11
insert into @map_new select 22

declare @map table(ID int not null, ID2 int not null)

insert into @map
select t.ID, t2.ID from @map_old t join @map_new t2 on  t.iden = t2.iden
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that this tables will have the same amount of rows.

Then maybe something like this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS RowNbr,
        mapNew.ID
    FROM
        @map_new AS mapNew
),CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS RowNbr,
        mapOld.ID
    FROM
        @map_old AS mapOld
)
INSERT INTO @map(ID,ID2)
SELECT
    CTE.ID,
    CTE2.ID
FROM
    CTE
    JOIN CTE2
        ON CTE.RowNbr=CTE2.RowNbr

SELECT * FROM @map
```